# How to fix "Required request part 'file' is not present" error when uploading image file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a problem when I try to send an (image) file from html to my spring controller, I did everything as same as when I send any other value but it keeps throwing this exact same error...

HTML

```
<form th:action="@{/changeLogo}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">                                     
    <input type="file" name="file"/>                                     
  </div>  

  <button type="submit" class="text-center btn btn-primary"> Upload </button>                                  
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/changeLogo")
public String changelogo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal){

    SystemUser systemUser = 
    systemUserService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    Company company = systemUser.getCompany();

        try {
            System.out.println("Picture exists:" + file);
            company.setLogo(file.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    companyRepository.saveAndFlush(company);
    return "redirect:/systemUser";
}
```

Comment: Have you add `multipartResolver` in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Yes, I did that first. Also, all dependencies are set.

Comment: please post error text

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
public String changelogo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal)
```

to

```
public String changelogo(MultipartHttpServletRequest file)
```

Comment: No need to remove `Principal`; it's available to all `@Controller` methods.

Comment: It actually still says "null" when I try to retrieve Multipart File out of it

Comment: @RobertHadzi-Mehmedovic where is your submit button ? you send data as ajax?

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani it's default type="submit", I accidentally deleted that part of code when I was posting sorry